# Active Directory Security Group and Role in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, role

I have a security group in AD. I want to assign Administrator role to members of that security group. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
if (User.IsInRole("AdminSecurityGroup"))
{
    //Give user admin authority
}
```